# Is there a name for this design pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, interface, types

I keep finding myself solving something similar to the [diamond inheritance problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem) (but without any inheritance!) as follows:

```
  type I<'a> =
     abstract member Foo : 'a

  type a =
     | A

     interface I<a> with
        member this.Foo = this

  type b =
     | B

     interface I<b> with
        member this.Foo = this
```

The commonality between the types `a` and `b` is exposed via the `I<_>` interface but members of the interface can return values of the specific underlying types `a` or `b` rather than having to be generalizing to any type implementing the interface.

For example, this returns a value of the type `a`:

```
> (A :> I<_>).Foo;;
val it : a = A
```

and this returns a value of the type `b`:

```
> (B :> I<_>).Foo;;
val it : b = B
```

even though the values were upcast to the interface type.

Is there a name for this? Are other people doing this?

Comment: For those who are not familiar with the term - [Diamond Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem)

Comment: Ontology maybe? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontology_%28information_science%29

Comment: @Jon - You referred to the term in the introduction to the question. I added a reference.

Comment: I see, thanks. I've added your link to the question itself.

Comment: I'm curious to know how you're using this. There have been many times I wished for multiple inheritance or something like Scala's traits in .NET. I'd love to know of some workarounds (preferably that work in other .NET languages as well and don't rely on F#'s type inference).

Comment: @Daniel: I am actually using this in production F# code to emulate overlapping sum types. You can do this directly in OCaml using polymorphic variants and I wanted to do this in F# in order to prove that some functions took an A, B or C and others took an A or B or a B or C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++, this is called the [Curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).